# recursive http request for finishline server is not working

Tags: c#, recursion

I am trying to make 2 request using recursion in c#

First request is working fine but second request is not working

```
public class Finishline 
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Finishline n = new Finishline();
        var a = n.lib_var("http://www.finishline.com/store/product?A=6961&categoryId=cat301644&productId=prod792423");
        Console.Write (a);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public string lib_var (string url)
    {
        Console.Write (url);

        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);


        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        request.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.8";

        var response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.Write ("hu");
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {

            var html = reader.ReadToEnd();
//Works upto here
            Console.Write (html);
//From thos it is not working
            lib_var ("http://www.finishline.com/store/catalog/ispu/ispuStoreLookup.jsp?latitude=34.0543797&longitude=-118.2672801&productId=prod792423&skuId=sku2622306");
            return html;

        }
    }
}
```

From second call

```
lib_var ("http://www.finishline.com/store/catalog/ispu/ispuStoreLookup.jsp?latitude=34.0543797&longitude=-118.2672801&productId=prod792423&skuId=sku2622306");
```

The program got stuck how to make second call work??

Comment: I didn't knew that your lib_var function accepts any parameter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code ends up in an infinite loop of sorts because your `lib_var` method always calls `lib_var` again. So the callstack goes: `lib_var -> lib_var -> lib_var -> lib_var -> ...`
and will never return back to `Main`.

Depending on what you want the program to do, there are different solutions to this problem:

1. you should move the second call out of the `lib_var` method into `Main`.

**lib_var**

```
 var html = reader.ReadToEnd();

//Works upto here
Console.Write (html);

//From thos it is not working
//lib_var ("http://www.finishline.com/store/catalog/ispu/ispuStoreLookup.jsp?latitude=34.0543797&longitude=-118.2672801&productId=prod792423&skuId=sku2622306");

return html;
```

**Main**

```
Finishline n = new Finishline();
var a = n.lib_var("http://www.finishline.com/store/product?A=6961&categoryId=cat301644&productId=prod792423");
Console.WriteLine(a);
var b = n.lib_var("http://www.finishline.com/store/catalog/ispu/ispuStoreLookup.jsp?latitude=34.0543797&longitude=-118.2672801&productId=prod792423&skuId=sku2622306");
Console.WriteLine(b);

Console.ReadLine();
```

2. Add a second parameter to lib_var specifying whether it should do the recursive call.

**lib_var**

```
public string lib_var (string url, bool doRecursive)
{
    // ...

    if (doRecursive) 
    {
        lib_var ("http://www.finishline.com/store/catalog/ispu/ispuStoreLookup.jsp?latitude=34.0543797&longitude=-118.2672801&productId=prod792423&skuId=sku2622306", false);
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
var a = n.lib_var("http://www.finishline.com/store/product?A=6961&categoryId=cat301644&productId=prod792423");
Console.WriteLine(a);
```